# WSO2 error code 500 when invoking the API at the first time

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm doing a stress test on an **API deployed** in **wso2 integrator server** with a high number of requests. Every stress test session. I always get the first response as fault response with an

> error code 500 (internal server error)

And the remaining responses are fine.

I noticed that if the session is expired and if I want to send a request with this session id, above problem is produced.

I'm using `wso2ei 6.5.0` as my server application version.
Can anyone help me please to avoid this message?

Comment: Are you using any Load Balancers infront of WSO2 EI?

Comment: Hi Arunan, no load balancers are used before the API. The invocation is directly with the rest client. i'm using jmeter locally for the stress tests

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following properties to the API sequence.

```
<property name="NO_KEEPALIVE" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
<property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
```

This will make sure that connections are properly closed in-between the test sessions.

Comment: Thanks Arunan. I will try this and come back ASAP.